# Replace a set of vectors in a list from another set of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I have lists

```
A = {{0,0.1,50,"A"},{200,0.2,120,"E"},{300,0.32,500,"G"},{400,0.33,800,"GO"}}

B={{0,0.1,821,"new1"},{310,0.32,911,"new"}}
```

I need to modify `A` with `B` to get

```
C = {{{0,0.1,821,"new"},{200,0.2,120,"E"},{310,0.32,911,"new"},{400,0.33,800,"GO"}}
```

my rule is whenever `A[[All,2]]` sees the new `B[[All,2]]` it replaces with that particular vector from `B`.

I can, of course, use loop and find and replace, is there any simple way to do this job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A/.Rule@@@Select[Tuples[{A,B}],#[[1,2]]===#[[2,2]]&]
```

> `{{0,0.1,821,"new1"},{200,0.2,120,"E"},{310,0.32,911,"new"},{400,0.33,800,"GO"}}`

Comment: @ yode, I appreciate your answer. I am sorry about my ignorance, Could you just give an idea of the use of "@@@" please? I know that @ represents mapping. Is there any difference between == and === ?

Comment: You can check [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)

Comment: But work [for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w0tAo.png).

Comment: I am sorry, I had made a mistake in the program,Please accept my apology.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps (apologies if I have misinterpreted):

```
A /. ({_, #[[2]], __} -> # & /@ B)
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
GatherBy[ Join[A, B], #[[2]] & ][[ All , -1]]
```

> {{0, 0.1, 821, "new1"}, {200, 0.2, 120, "E"}, {310, 0.32, 911, 
>     "new"}, {400, 0.33, 800, "GO"}}

If order does not matter:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join[B, A], #[[2]] &]
```

Comment: Little shorter `Last /@ GatherBy[Join[A, B], #[[2]] &]`

Comment: @yode yep, though I decided to use this as it should be faster for bigger lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[{x__}] := {x};
(f[{_, #[[2]], __}] = #) & /@ B;

f /@ A
{{0, 0.1`, 821, "new1"}, {200, 0.2`, 120, "E"}, {310, 0.32`, 911, "new"},
 {400, 0.33`, 800, "GO"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Module[{alternatives = Alternatives @@ B[[All, 2]]},
Map[If[MatchQ[#[[2]], alternatives], 
First@Cases[B, {_, #[[2]], ___}], #] &, A]]

(* {{0, 0.1, 821, "new1"}, {200, 0.2, 120, "E"}, {310, 0.32, 911,"new"},
{400, 0.33, 800, "GO"}} *)


A /. {_, x_Real, __} /; MatchQ[x, Alternatives @@ B[[All, 2]]] :> 
First@Cases[B, {_, x, __}]

(* {{0, 0.1, 821, "new1"}, {200, 0.2, 120, "E"}, {310, 0.32, 911,"new"}, 
{400, 0.33, 800, "GO"}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

`A[[All, 2]] /. Thread[#[[All, 2]] ->  #]& @ Join[B, A]`

> {{0, 0.1, 821, "new1"}, {200, 0.2, 120, "E"}, {310, 0.32, 911, 
>     "new"}, {400, 0.33, 800, "GO"}}